# 70 leagues under the lunar maria

Tags: science-based, moons, near-future

The internal structure of the Moon is different from that of the Earth. There are neither volcanos nor many moonquakes. Using early 21st century technology, could we dig a vertical mine shaft all the way to the core? Can we live in the underground city without exposing ourselves to cosmic rays using existing technology probably in coming decades?

Comment: Related: http://what-if.xkcd.com/46/. Of course, gravity of moon is weaker, but the holes proposed in the forum are way more superficial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no real reason to dig all the way to the core.  a couple meters of lunar surface is all that is needed to protect us from cosmic radiation.  So as JDlugosz was pointing out, occupying old lava tubes would be the fastest way to start a lunar colony.  The lava tubes already have open space that can be filled and many will be deep enough to provide the needed protection with minimal digging.  they can of course be reinforced and extended to be more accommodating but no real reason to dig 1,000 miles or even 10 into the moons surface.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing pressure would eventually collapse the tunnel to the core, even in the lighter gravitational field of the Moon, although you could almost certainly dig far deeper into the Moon than the Earth.

Planets and bodies like the Moon are spherical because on that scale, even the strongest materials are like liquids rather than solids, and the pressure causes them to flow, eventually turning granite, iron and anything else into a spherical "droplet".

It might be necessary or desirable to dig very deep into the Moon for various reasons (although as noted you don't have to go down very far for radiation protection, and some valuable materials like 3He are actually bound to grains of regolith on the surface). Stephen Baxter in "Manifold Space" postulated that water might be bound in the mineral particles in the mantel of large planets, and in his novel a giant shaft is driven into the Moon's mantel to tap the water trapped in there. As a BTW, this theory also suggests that up to 3X the amount of water in the Earth's oceans is trapped in the same way in the Earth's mantel, so running out of water might not be a problem if the technology is developed to really drill that deep.